# Can I say "I got to be reluctant to go to school"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Can I say

> I got to be reluctant to go to school.

In the morning, I thought I wanted to go to school (for evening class). But after lunch, now I don't want to go to school. My feeling changed. I've come to be reluctant.

In this context, which is correct in order to express my current changed feeling?

> I got to be reluctant to go to school

or

> I became reluctant to go to school.

I'd like to ask expression using "get" and "become". Or both is inapropriate for this situation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**got to be** can mean the same as become. This meaning is quite informal: you might say it, but in British English you probably wouldn't write it.

The main usage is when you achieve something or have chance to do something (HAVE CHANCE in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-to).

> I was working there for five years before I got to be a manager.

It can also mean BEGIN (starting to become), but it is generally used in a progressive tense for this meaning.

> I am getting to be reluctant to go to school.

If you are already reluctant to go to school, you should use **become**

> I became reluctant to go to school

Answer (score 0):

To describe a change in feeling, "become + (adjective)" is used:

> I've become reluctant to go to school.

"I've got to" and "I got to (gotta)" are colloquial patterns that mean "I have to be" or "I must be".

> I gotta be the best. (I have to be the best)
>   I gotta go to school now. (I have to go to school)